# Any alternative of "newrelic-winston" package?

Tags: logging, nestjs, newrelic, winston

I am using NESTJS application and New Relic to see logs.
To send logs  I am using the winston and newrelic-winston packages.
But I see newrelic-winston is depreciated.
Do you know any alternative for that one?

```
const NewrelicWinston = require('newrelic-winston');
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import { utilities as nestWinstonModuleUtilities } from 'nest-winston/dist/winston.utilities';

const configs = {
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        nestWinstonModuleUtilities.format.nestLike(),
      ),
    };

    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
      logger: WinstonModule.createLogger({
        transports: [
          new winston.transports.Console(configs),
          new NewrelicWinston(configs),
        ],
      }),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Winston 3.0.0 or higher is supported for Node.js agent.

Check out this New Relic Doc for more information: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/logs/logs-context/configure-logs-context-nodejs/#automatic

(Suggestion: Make sure that the customer is using latest Node agent)